# Unable to install Alpha SSL certificate for Openfire

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate, openfire

I have been issued an SSL certificate for www.mydomain.com, I have been able to successfully implement the certificate for the site and the site is working is https.

However, I have not been able to install the SSL in the Openfire. I have tried every method.

Also, when I try importing the certificate from the web admin panel, it shows me the following error :

```
There was an error one importing private key and signed certificate. Error message: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCERSAPrivateCrtKey cannot be cast to java.security.KeyPair
```

I have been trying this for days now. I have tried almost every tutorial out there. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: By chance are you giving it just the key, instead of the keypair?

Comment: As in?? With the intermediate key as well you mean?? 

This is what I am doing : In the key field, I am putting the contents of the www_mydomain_com.key and in the Other Field, I am putting the concatinated www_mydomain_key.crt + intermediate.crt